# How to add one BottomNavigationBarItem only

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a BottomNavigationBar which I need to add only one centralized button inside, but I am getting this error:

> 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar.dart': Failed assertion: line 191 pos 15: 'items.length >= 2': is not true.

which is logical as the flutter's source code has this condition:

```dart
//..
assert(items.length >= 2),
```

So, here's my code, is there a workaround for this using BottomNavigationBar to keep the code clean?

```dart
BottomNavigationBar(

   items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      buildBottomNavigationBarItem(
         iconData: Icons.close,
      ),

// AN ERROR AFTER COMMENTING THIS:

//    buildBottomNavigationBarItem(
//       iconData: Icons.open,
//    ),
   ],
),


BottomNavigationBarItem buildBottomNavigationBarItem(
      {IconData iconData, String title = ''}
    ) {
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(
        iconData,
        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        size: 0.04 * _deviceHeight,
      ),
      title: Text(
        title,
      ),
    );
}
```

thanks

Comment: You cant. From docs: "The bottom navigation bar consists of multiple items".

Comment: I see. thank you for your response, I hope if there's a workaround or something..?

Comment: I don't understand though why doesn't Flutter allow just 1 item in the BottomNavigationBar? Why are custom solutions needed at all when it can be provided directly in BottomNavigationBar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use `BottomNavigationBar` but instead of it you can create your own widget and pass it into the `bottomNavigationBar` parameter.

[image: Demo]

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Text('Hi'),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          height: 60,
          color: Colors.black12,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => print('tap on close'),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  ),
                  Text('close'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If the new, custom bottom navigation bar overlaps with the phone's OS GUI, you can wrap the `InkWell` with a `SafeArea` widget.

Comment: I ended up with something like this, but even so I voted you up. thank you ))

Comment: I believe there is a problem with iphone 11. The navigation bar seems to cover the button: https://i.imgur.com/6JConN9.png

Comment: @Anraiki You can always add a SafeAreaWidget https://gist.github.com/kherel/ebb8cd7004c8a62d481bb85c4cd08b9f

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `assert(items.length >= 2),` to the length you want in the bottom navigation bar if you want to have three items turn the `assert(items.length >= 2),` to `assert(items.length >= 3),`

Comment: If you want 1 turn the assert(items.lenght <= 1), and put 1 item in the list {BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_box_outlined),
            label: 'Contact',
            backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
          ),}

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mohamed. Actually asserts purpose is to handle mismatches of parameters given to a specific Widget/Function. So the answer above here describes the solution :)

Comment: Where do you change this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one item (BottomNavigationBarItem) in your BottomNavigationBar items[] you get this error. Please add at least one more item in your items[] (>=2)