# I want to add a buttombar to my application Contains only text flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text

I want to add a `buttombar` to my application Contains only just one  `text` with background color .
I need it to write the copyright in my application,  but I find just that I have to add At least a two-item
In the list,
I don't need this
Just i want to add a single one `text` with a `background` color

Comment: Can you show the code and tell what error is occuring!?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you do not need a bottombar widget.
you can create a container with specific height and background color and center a text widget in the container.

Comment: Yes but when I do that I get a overflowed error in different screen sizes even I used media query and expended

Comment: If you used Expanded correctly you should be good. It automatically adapts to screen sizes. @imenlakrib

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to add bottomNavigationBar with one item only you can just write your own widget in the bottom navigation bar like a Container and set a background of your choice and give it a child widget wrapped in an INKWELL or GESTUREDETECTOR and if it overlaps with the Phone's GUI you can wrap the inkwell with SAFEAREA widget

Comment: You can check this answer to understand -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57911502/how-to-add-one-bottomnavigationbaritem-only